# Functions and numpy array preallocation

Tags: python, performance, function, numpy

How to optimize functions involving numpy arrays?

Use case:

```
def create_array_and_fill(a, b, N):
    res = np.zeros(N, N)

    res[0] = a
    res[-1] = b

    return res

c = create_array_and_fill(5, 9, 100)
```

But then, sometimes, I know beforehand the maximum size of all arrays that I need to use (say for testing purposes), so what's the best way to go? Should I preallocate and what is the best way to do so? For example, can I pass a preallocated array to a function so that the function just updates it instead of returning a new one?

My first ideas is as follows but, of course, it comes with a cost, I have to change all my function signatures now.

```
def create_array_and_fill(a, b, N, res):

    res[0] = a
    res[-1] = b

    # No more return here?

c = np.zeros(N, N)
create_array_and_fill(a, b, N, c)
```

Comment: It depends on the function.  You can pass a preallocated array to a function if that function is set up to allow passing a preallocated array.  You'd need to be more specific to get a more specific answer.

Comment: I can change the function signature if need be, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you could do something like this:

```
def fill_array(a, b, N, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = np.zeros(N, N)
    out[0] = a
    out[-1] = b
    return out
```

This modifies the `out` object if one is provided, or returns a new one if no `out` is provided.  In this case it still returns the value even if modifying an existing one, but you could easily modify it to return None instead if an expl;icit `out` was provided.

But yes, you're going to have to change your functions if you want them to work either way (with a given "out" array or by creating a new array).  If you wrote code in a function that creates a new array, there's no magical way to make it not execute that code just because you have another array pre-created.  You have to edit your function.